# How to call non-const method when a const method with the same signature exists?

Tags: c++, opencv

OpenCV's [Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) class contains the following two methods:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline
_Tp* Mat::ptr(int y)
{
    CV_DbgAssert( y == 0 || (data && dims >= 1 && (unsigned)y < (unsigned)size.p[0]) );
    return (_Tp*)(data + step.p[0] * y);
}

template<typename _Tp> inline
const _Tp* Mat::ptr(int y) const
{
    CV_DbgAssert( y == 0 || (data && dims >= 1 && (unsigned)y < (unsigned)size.p[0]) );
    return (const _Tp*)(data + step.p[0] * y);
}
```

and in my code I have the following line:

```
uchar* row_ptr = input_img.ptr<uchar>(0);
```

which genereates the compile-time error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const unsigned char*’ to ‘uchar*’ {aka ‘unsigned char*’}
```

The method that is called is const, but a non-const method with the same name and argument list exists. How can I specify that I want to use the non-const version of the method? Thank you.

Comment: is `input_img` really non-const ? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: you typically "select" it by calling the method on an object of right constness. The easiest way to explain the error is when `input_img` is `const`. Thats why we need to see a complete example

Comment: If the `const` overload is chosen, then that means that `input_img` is `const`. Why do you want to call a non-`const` method on a `const` object/reference? That is exactly what `const` is there to prevent. It seems your design has some problem with const-correctness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically  you don't "select" which function to call, but the compiler will call the right function for you.

Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    int bar() { return 1;};
    int bar() const { return 2;}
};

int main(){ 
    const foo f;
    foo f2;
    std::cout << f.bar();
    std::cout << f2.bar();
}
```

The output is

```
21
```

Because you can only call the `const` function `bar` on a `const foo`. Calling the non-const method would potentially modify it, hence you cannot call it when the object is `const`.

When the object is not `const` then both could be called but the non-const one is called. Only in this case you can "select", for example:

```
 const foo& const_f = f;
 const_f.bar();
```

This now calls the const method, even though the actual object (`f`) isn't `const`, because the method is called using a reference to const.

TL;DR: The error suggests that `input_img` is either a const `Mat` or a const reference. Hence you can only call the `const` overload. If you want to call the other you need a non-const reference.